# .htaccess rewrite rule with string replacement in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect URLs which having a specific string in url. I want to replace `/new-site-connect` with `/financing`.

From

```
example.com/about-us/new-site-connect/lead-aba/?utm_source=InterestList&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campus1&utm_content=PreQualifyNow
```

To

```
example.com/about-us/financing/lead-aba/?utm_source=InterestList&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campus1&utm_content=PreQualifyNow
```

I tried it following methods. But no one work

```
RewriteRule ^/about-us/new-site-connect/(.*)$ /about-us/financing/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/new-site-connect(.*) /about-us/financing$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is in htaccess context, you can not use the leading `/` characters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(about-us)/new-site-connect/(.*)$ /$1/financing/$2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve this with. Please find below solution:

Redirect permanent /about-us/new-site-connect/ example.com/about-us/financing/