# Changing / replace multiple URL parameters with htaccess / mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I got this working snippet to change a query parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)&?name=(.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^pokladna/?$  $0?%1name_gls=%2 [R=301,L]
```

from here [.htaccess rewrite rule with string replacement in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678884/htaccess-rewrite-rule-with-string-replacement-in-url)

But in my case I need to replace multiple query parameters.

For example: `https://example.com/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=campaignname`

needs to be `https://example.com/?mtm_source=source&mtm_medium=banner&mtm_campaign=campaignname`

There might be other parameters before, after or in between, which should not be affected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?utm_source=([^&]*)&utm_medium=([^&]*)&utm_campaign=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /\?mtm_source=%1&mtm_medium=%2&mtm_campaign=%3 [QSA,L]
```

---

---

***Generic solution:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?(?:[^=]*)=([^&]*)&(?:[^=]*)=([^&]*)&(?:[^=]*)=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /\?mtm_source=%1&mtm_medium=%2&mtm_campaign=%3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! While this would work for this case I forgot to specify, that the parameter could be in a different order or other parameters might be before, after or inbetween.

Comment: @EscapeNetscape, sure let me quickly edit it and let you know then, cheers.

Comment: @EscapeNetscape, Please do check my Generic solution once and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That does somehow not work. I created a htaccess - tester link with an exampe: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=0912d2a3-7500-4d6b-832d-a671d340b1a4 There I have the working rules in a row but only the last one applys.

Comment: @EscapeNetscape, I am sorry to say but these online sites are NOT good and we can't trust them so better not to use them and test rules in apache itself, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can replace multiple query parameters that start with `utm_` to their counterparts that start with `mtm_`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# this rule will find any of the 3 utm_ query parameters and will
# replace each with the mtm_ query parameter. N flag is used here to 
# make this rule loop until all query parameters have been replaced
# in the end it sets an env variable MTM to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?u(tm_(?:source|medium|campaign)=[^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1m%2%3 [N,DPI,E=MTM:1]

# if env variable MTM is 1 then do an external redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:MTM} =1
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

# other rules go below this line
```

Once satisfied with the result replace `302` with `301` (permanent redirect).

This needs to be tested on a local Apache web server not on any online test facility.